# PowerShell acl error while executing it as script

Tags: windows, powershell, acl

When I run the following commands as a powershell script I get the following error message and it fails.
My main goal is to create a directory and to assign the necessary rights to it .
the error is

```
Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified."
At C:\setup.ps1:38 char:1
+ $Acl.AddAccessRule($ACE)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

my script (setup.ps1) contains the following, so I expect the assignment of the permissions
when I run it line by line it works....but not as a script

```
mkdir "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dir1"
$identity = 'iis apppool\MyAppPool'
$rights = 'Modify' 
$inheritance = 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit' 
$propagation = 'None'
$type = 'Allow' 
$ACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($identity,$rights,$inheritance,$propagation, $type)
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dir1"
$Acl.AddAccessRule($ACE)
Set-Acl -Path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dir1" -AclObject $Acl
```

Comment: Are you running the script with the same rights as the powershell session you run "line by line"? Also maybe you need to insert a Start-Sleep before the $ACE command. It's possible your script is executing so fast that it does not see the new directory and when you run line by line it takes more time.